# How do I add the “extended attributes” on a file in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, attributes, xattr

How do I add the extended attributes?

I am using excel with local file links and opening files but I need to add extended attributes to each file. So I do not get the prompt `Grand File Access`.

My files looks like File-01.html...File-99.html.

I need to add the xattr `com.apple.quarantine: 0002;580fbaf1;Microsoft Excel;` to every *.html file. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using the `xattr` command? Or is the issue that setting `com.apple.quarantine` doesn't do what you expect? If the latter then I think you'll find that attribute is private to Apple and its format not public. HTH

Comment: @CRD I do not know how to use the xattr command.

Comment: Try opening Terminal and typing `man xattr`, or look in Xcode documentation, or search on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xattr -w myattr myattrvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

[*"There's an app for that"*](https://eclecticlight.co/xattred-sandstrip-xattr-tools/). `xattred` - the extended attribute editor will help you do that. `xattred` is a GUI app, and may not be exactly what you  want for editing 100 files, but it will help you get your `xattr` construction formulated quickly, and then switch to the CLI tool `xattr` for the repetetive operation.